# What is difference between ViewData, @Html.ViewData and @Ajax.ViewData?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, viewdata

I have tried to understand but somemore details if anybody knows why it behave like that.

**Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult TestView()
        {
            ViewData["UserInfoData"] = "From User Info Action";            
            return View();
        }
```

**View (TestView.cshtml)**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserInfo";
    ViewData["UserInfoData"] = "This is the problem";    
}

@Html.ViewData["UserInfoData"].ToString()
<br />
@Ajax.ViewData["UserInfoData"].ToString()
<br />
@ViewData["UserInfoData"].ToString()
```

> When I execute above action it return view and output is like following
>   From User Info Action
>   From User Info Action
>   This is the problem

Why @Html.ViewData and @Ajax.ViewData points to different viewdata than ViewData  ? What is use of that ?

Also in above view @ViewBag.Title and this I am able to access view @ViewData["Title"] but not with @Html and @Ajax. It seems that it points to different ViewDataDicitionary that is being created or passed from controller and not 
that updated on View ?

I have tried to look at detail and found that @Html and @Ajax both relies on ViewDataContainer and it points to some compile cshtml class and what is ViewDataContainer ? What is use of that ?

dotnetfiddle link : https://dotnetfiddle.net/U7s25u

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The code you have shown will output _This is the problem_ 3 times (not _From User Info Action_). And what do you mean _Why `@Html.ViewData` and `@Ajax.ViewData` points to different data_? - they don't, and even your own code proves it

Comment: Yes This is from my own code. I am using MVC 5. I have added screenshot of code and output.

Comment: So am I, and I cut an pasted your code, and it outputs 3 identical _This is the problem_. What your claiming is simply impossible unless you have other code causing the issue

Comment: Which MVC Version ? Exact DLL version ?

Comment: `5.2.3.0`, but also tested in MVC-4

Comment: In 5.2.3 they [switched to copy-on-write `ViewData`s](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/12/17/asp-net-mvc-5-2-3-web-pages-3-2-3-and-web-api-5-2-3-beta-releases/). So initially all `ViewData`s point to the same object but they are cloned when changes are made.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have added for debugging screenshot as well.

Comment: @GSerg I have same feeling.

Comment: @dotnetstep, Which version are you using? And you asked _Why `@Html.ViewData` and `@Ajax.ViewData` points to different data_ but your own screenshots show that both output "From User Info Action" (only `@ViewData["UserInfoData"].ToString()` is different in the screenshot)

Comment: I am using 5.2.2 0 and my question is why Ajax and HTML helper point different data then viewdata last output.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have added dotnetfiddle link and that highlight same issue.

Comment: @StephenMuecke If you used 5.2.2.0 version you will get my output and if you use 5.2.3.0 version or later then you will This is the problem 3 times.